# In which version of hibernate @JoinColumnsOrFormulas is introduced?

Tags: java, hibernate

We are using hibernate v3.3. I am not sure why am not able to use the annotation `@JoinColumnsOrFormulas` since eclipse throws not found error. Can you please let me know from which version of hibernate this annotation was introduced?

Comment: I believe it's Hibernate 3.5

Comment: yeps, hibernate-annotations-3.5.0-Final

Answer (score 0):

@JoinColumnOrFormula is introduced in `Hibernate-3.5`, you can verify it using the API's for different versions of hibernate.

[Hibernate 3.5 API](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/) has the Java doc for [@JoinColumnsOrFormula](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/annotations/JoinColumnOrFormula.html)

Below version of API's will not have this annotation:

[Hibernate-3.2](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/)

[Hibernate-3.3](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/api/)